# Django 3.0, messages framework experiencing troubles

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, middleware, django-3.0

I recently tried to upgrade a django website to the latest Django and messages started to give me an error. It seems as though the wsgi module cannot load the message part of the request.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hm/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/api.py", line 21, in add_message
    messages = request._messages
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute '_messages'
```

I have already checked messages is installed in the apps part of the settings and middleware_classes contains the sessions middleware and the messages middleware.

I have also re-ran the migrations and migrated successfully the database.

I am using Django 3.0 and Python3.8.

The final error message it throws is

```
django.contrib.messages.api.MessageFailure: You cannot add messages without installing django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware
```

Comment: Have you followed the steps [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/#enabling-messages) to enable messages for your application?

Comment: Yes. Its the first thing I did. I think I have gotten around this error by using both 
    MIDDLEWARE = [    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',] then MIDDELWARE_CLASSES = [...]